# Solr search not returing documents

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to implement **PorterStemFilterFactory** in my analyzer during indexing .But when i query for documents,the output dont have documents which I got before adding the above analyzer.How can I get documents with both stemming and normal filters.

schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
     <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" replacement=" "/>  
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

when I search for query "agile" with below analyzer,it returned documents where the query were found.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
     <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" replacement=" "/>  
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Give some example of what you are trying to search ? something which worked before ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `PorterStemFilterFactory` removes common endings from words.

In your case the word `agile` is reduced to `agil`.

You can check here https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/voc.txt. (search here for the word agile).

Now search here for the corresponding output after applying Porter Stemming. https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/output.txt

You will see you cant find the word `agile` , because it is stemmed to `agil`.

That is why you are not able to search for `agile`, since there is no document that exists with that word . try searching for `agil` and you should see the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Its working as you suggested.But how can I  query "agile" and get the same results with stemming filter applied to the analyzer.

Comment: Add  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/> to query  analyzer also and try

Answer (score 0):

Using "solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" will generate token as `agil`

I suggest you to use

`<filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>`

post filter `agile` will be same `agile`

use filters as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This helps to match the plurals.